# How to compute immediate each row visited Elapsed time in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I want to compute immediate elapsed time between each click event in SQL Server. So basically, when user click on any particular `Etype` from the same `source`, it should compute the immediate elapsed time. The calculation will be done from `StartTime`.

Here is the Table structure

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[EmpLog](
    [EmpId] [int] NOT NULL,        
    [StartTime] [datetime] NULL,
    [Source] [nvarchar](128) NULL,
    [EType] [nvarchar](128) NULL,
    [User] [nvarchar](64) NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_EmpLog] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [EmpId] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
```

Insert statement

```
INSERT INTO EmpLog (EmpId, StartTime, Source,EType,User) VALUES (1,'2021-02-20 01:15:44.647', 'PEn', 'In','abc','2050');
INSERT INTO EmpLog (EmpId, StartTime, Source,EType,User) VALUES (2,'2021-02-21 02:15:45.647', 'PEn', 'In','abc','2050');
INSERT INTO EmpLog (EmpId, StartTime, Source,EType,User) VALUES (3,'2021-02-22 01:15:44.647', 'PEn', 'In','abc','2050');
INSERT INTO EmpLog (EmpId, StartTime, Source,EType,User) VALUES (4,'2021-02-23 01:15:44.647', 'PEn', 'In','abc','2050');
INSERT INTO EmpLog (EmpId, StartTime, Source,EType,User) VALUES (5,'2021-02-24 01:15:44.647', 'PEn', 'In','abc','2');
INSERT INTO EmpLog (EmpId, StartTime, Source,EType,User) VALUES (6,'2021-02-24 01:15:46.647', 'PEn', 'OP','abc','0');
INSERT INTO EmpLog (EmpId, StartTime, Source,EType,User) VALUES (7,'2021-02-24 01:15:48.647', 'PEn', 'ED','abcd','0');
INSERT INTO EmpLog (EmpId, StartTime, Source,EType,User) VALUES (8,'2021-02-24 01:15:50.647', 'HM', 'Dash','efg','0');
INSERT INTO EmpLog (EmpId, StartTime, Source,EType,User) VALUES (9,'2021-02-24 01:15:52.647', 'Chk', 'Sup','cde','0');
```

This query gives me elapsed time between each user click in SQL Server. But the problem is that I have same `user` and same `source` but different dates. Still is calculating the elapsed time. In the above case, It should compute `0` if the date is different.
The condition applies in the same date as well where the difference between each click greater than 5 minutes. It should display `0`.

1. Even the user and source are same but different datetime then it should compute `0`.
2. Difference between each click is greater than 5 minutes then compute `0` even the source and user are same.

We are only considering immediate click where click difference is less than 5 minutes.

Not sure how to consider these scenarios in my query.

```
SELECT 
    EmpId
    , [Source]
    , EType
    , [User] 
    , ABS(ISNULL(DATEDIFF(second, previousStartTime, StartTime), 0)) AS ElapsedTime
FROM   
    (
    SELECT  *,
            LEAD(StartTime) OVER ( PArtition by [Source], [User] ORDER BY StartTime) 
            AS  previousStartTime
    FROM    [dbo].[EmpLog]
   ) q

 ORDER BY  EmpId
```

The current output is

| EmpId | StartTime | Source | EType | User | ElapseTime |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2021-02-20 01:15:44.647 | PEn | In | abc | 2050 |
| 2 | 2021-02-21 02:15:45.647 | PEn | In | abc | 2050 |
| 3 | 2021-02-22 01:15:44.647 | PEn | In | abc | 2050 |
| 4 | 2021-02-23 01:15:44.647 | PEn | In | abc | 2050 |
| 5 | 2021-02-24 01:15:44.647 | PEn | In | abc | 2 |
| 6 | 2021-02-24 01:15:46.647 | PEn | OP | abc | 0 |
| 7 | 2021-02-24 01:15:48.647 | PEn | ED | abcd | 0 |
| 8 | 2021-02-24 01:15:50.647 | HM | Dash | efg | 0 |
| 9 | 2021-02-24 01:15:52.647 | Chk | Sup | cde | 0 |

The expected output should be

| EmpId | StartTime | Source | EType | User | ElapseTime |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2021-02-20 01:15:44.647 | PEn | In | abc | 0 |
| 2 | 2021-02-21 02:15:45.647 | PEn | In | abc | 0 |
| 3 | 2021-02-22 01:15:44.647 | PEn | In | abc | 0 |
| 4 | 2021-02-23 01:15:44.647 | PEn | In | abc | 0 |
| 5 | 2021-02-24 01:15:44.647 | PEn | In | abc | 2 |
| 6 | 2021-02-24 01:15:46.647 | PEn | OP | abc | 0 |
| 7 | 2021-02-24 01:15:48.647 | PEn | ED | abcd | 0 |
| 8 | 2021-02-24 01:15:50.647 | HM | Dash | efg | 0 |
| 9 | 2021-02-24 01:15:52.647 | Chk | Sup | cde | 0 |

Comment: @RjLearn . . . I'm baffled by what your question is.  You specify that you want to calculate an elapsed time.  Then your sample results make it look like you want to *filter* the results.  But you don't explain that at all in the question.

Comment: @DaleK, I have modified my question. Could you please assist? Thanks

Comment: @GordonLinoff,  Sorry. I updated my question. I do not want to filter rather I want to compute elapsed time. Thanks

Comment: @DaleK, please have a look now. Added `INSERT` statement as well. Hope this helps to provide me an answer. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can exclude the 2 conditions you mention using `CASE` expressions as follows:

```
SELECT
    EmpId
    , [Source]
    , EType
    , [User] 
    -- Only return a result when its less then 5 mins
    , CASE WHEN ElapsedTime < 300 then ElapsedTime ELSE 0 END AS ElapsedTime
FROM (
    SELECT *,
        LEAD(StartTime) OVER (PARTITION BY [Source], [User] ORDER BY StartTime) AS PreviousStartTime
    FROM dbo.EmpLog
) q
-- Only return a result when its the same day. The 5min filter will remove any from the same day in a different month
CROSS APPLY (VALUES(CASE WHEN DATEPART(day, PreviousStartTime) = DATEPART(day,StartTime) THEN ABS(ISNULL(DATEDIFF(second, PreviousStartTime, StartTime), 0)) ELSE 0 END)) AS X (ElapsedTime)
ORDER BY EmpId;
```

Which is functionally equivalent to the following query, but more compact. I include it to explain the logic.

```
SELECT
    EmpId
    , [Source]
    , EType
    , [User] 
    -- Only return a result when its less then 5 mins
    , CASE WHEN ElapsedTime < 300 then ElapsedTime ELSE 0 END AS ElapsedTime
FROM (
    SELECT
        EmpId
        , [Source]
        , EType
        , [User]
        -- Only return a result when its the same day. The 5min filter will remove any from the same day in a different month
        , CASE WHEN DATEPART(day, PreviousStartTime) = DATEPART(day,StartTime) THEN ABS(ISNULL(DATEDIFF(second, PreviousStartTime, StartTime), 0)) ELSE 0 END AS ElapsedTime
    FROM (
        SELECT *,
            LEAD(StartTime) OVER (PARTITION BY [Source], [User] ORDER BY StartTime) AS PreviousStartTime
        FROM dbo.EmpLog
    ) q
) v
ORDER BY EmpId;
```

Comment: Hi @DaleK, you are awesome man! Thank you so much.

Comment: Hi @DaleK, a little confusion here. I was playing around changing Date. The first Date is `2021-07-15 08:27:00.000` and the nextDate is `2021-07-15 09:14:00.000`. If I see closely, there is more than 5 minute difference between these 2 dates. So it should display `0`. But currently it is computing `2820`.

Comment: @RjLearn so thats a bit of a bug, but a fairly obvious one, why don't you see if you can work it out yourself? I've indicated where the 5min check is... see what you can find.

Comment: I just changed `18000` to `300` and it worked for me now. Thanks

Comment: @RjLearn there you go... much better that you learn to debug your code than ask us.